Chrome marked existing animation as invalidated when starting new animation
I found chrome will do a huge Recalculate Style and Pre-Paint for existing animations when I start a new animation wherever on the page. Is this by design or a Chromium bug? Imagine my real web page has thousands of DOM nodes and hundreds of existing animations, doing such animation invalidation will cause a huge CPU spike. Any ways I can avoid this?
PS:

normally chrome devtools won't show invalidation detail, go to devtools settings > Experiments > check Performance panel: invalidation tracking, and there you go.
I deliberately throttled cpu 20 times down to clearly show the problem cause the repro has much less DOM nodes than real scenario.


The reproducible code is pretty simple. I defined five floating elements running animation when the page starts. I also defined five backup elements which have content and classNames already. Then click the button to periodically start a new animation. To not introduce other factors that way cause reflow or relayout, I'm using Web Animation API instead of toggling className to start a new animation.


const keyframes = [{
    transform: "initial",
    willChange: "transform"
  },
  {
    transform: "translateX(0)",
    offset: 0.01,
    willChange: "transform"
  },
  {
    transform: "translateX(-100vw)",
    willChange: "initial"
  }
];
const timing = {
  duration: 3000,
  iterations: Infinity,
  easing: "linear"
};

const startButton = document.querySelector('#start');
startButton.onclick = start;

function start() {
  const backupList = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".backup"));
  let index = 0;
  setInterval(() => {
    if (index >= backupList.length) return;
    const div = backupList[index];
    div.animate(keyframes, timing);
    index++;
  }, 1000);
}
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

.floating,
.backup {
  position: absolute;
  will-change: transform;
  color: black;
  top: 0;
  left: 100vw;
}

.floating {
  animation: float linear 3s infinite;
}

@keyframes float {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100vw);
  }
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="floating">floating</div>
  <div class="floating">floating</div>
  <div class="floating">floating</div>
  <div class="floating">floating</div>
  <div class="floating">floating</div>
  <div class="backup">backup</div>
  <div class="backup">backup</div>
  <div class="backup">backup</div>
  <div class="backup">backup</div>
  <div class="backup">backup</div>
</div>
<button id="start">Start</button>



